ssh permission denied while running jenkins

+ ssh -i /home/ubuntu/myphpApp/key.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx /bin/bash
Warning: Identity file /home/ubuntu/myphpApp/key.pem not accessible: Permission denied.
ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx: Permission denied (publickey).
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE


trying to connect to ec2 from current server , not working. Tried with 400 600 777 keyfile permission, still not working.

Is Jenkins running as the ubuntu user?

-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1679 Jul 25 19:28 /home/ubuntu/myphpApp/key.pem

and the directory's the file is in are readable?

/home/ubuntu/myphpApp/key.pem must have a 600 permission and be owned by the jenkins user.
it will not work on a different permission, even if it's 777.
Preferably use jenkins ssh credential by storing the privet key in an ssh privet key credential.
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'myphpapp', keyFileVariable: 'ssh')]) {
    sh 'ssh -i $ssh ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx /bin/bash'
}


ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-154:~/myphpApp$ ls -l /home/ubuntu/myphpApp/key.pem
-rw------- 1 jenkins jenkins 1679 Jul 25 19:28 /home/ubuntu/myphpApp/key.pem
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-xx:~/myphpApp$ ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@x.x.x.x
Load key "key.pem": Permission denied
ubuntu@x.x.x.x: Permission denied (publickey).

first you have to be jenkins not ubuntu: sudo su jenkins --shell=/bin/sh jenkins jenkins@ip-10-0-1-xx:~/myphpApp$ ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@x.x.x.x Load key. or change the file owner to Ubuntu because you are using the Ubuntu user.     chown ubuntu  /home/ubuntu/myphpApp/key.pem

run : whoami in your Jenkinsfile and see wish user you are running the command as.then change the ownership of the file to that user.

Yeah, worked thank you so much.

Accept an answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
